# Test webservice method for object types of data

Tags: web-services, api

I have a web service containing a method with object type data. When I want to test this method using the webservice api it suggests like,

```
The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters.
```

So, I am not able to test the service by passing object type data.

Is there any way simpler to test such method ? Any links, blogs etc ?

I am using .NET technology.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write an integration test that points to your web service and sends a request to it.

It depends on the technology you're using, but in the .Net world you would generate a proxy and call methods on it from the test.

Answer (score 0):

The is an add-in for firefox than can be useful for you.

[HTTP Resource Test](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/http-resource-test/)

You can tailor your own http request.

Just need to know how your object type data is XML serialized and create a XML SOAP request.